# Is the MUI Langauge Pack for Windows 7 available?

Tags: windows-7, language

I just installed Windows 7 Enterprise from my MSDN account onto my dev and test machines. I found that the handwriting recognition previously found on my Windows Vista Home Premium and Ultimate (both retail) machines are no longer available in Win7.

I also read that these can be enabled via the use of the Multilingual User Interface Language Pack (MUI Language Packs), but I'm unable to find this in MSDN?

Is it not available?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows 7 you could install language packs via Windows Update. Check out [this](http://windows7center.com/tutorials/how-to-download-and-install-windows-7-beta-language-packs-mui-packs/) tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of *how* to install the language pack, problem is I'm not seeing them in windows update, and I can't find such a download anywhere - via microsoft's public download site or MSDN.

Comment: Hmm... A simple case of "when it's done" perhaps? The updates for the language pack suddenly showed up in Windows update in each of the istalled machines as of yesterday.